# Get value from MySQL table, show only top ten highest and top ten lowest

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this:

```
  Username    Rating
1 xxxxxxxx      -1
2 xxxxxxxx       2
3 xxxxxxxx       5
4 xxxxxxxx      -2
5 xxxxxxxx       4
```

(Imagine if the table was bigger and had more than 20 rows). I want to write a MySQL statement in PHP that will return two lists: a list of the top ten highest values ordered by largest first, and a list of the top ten lowest values, ordered lowest first. How would I go about this?

Comment: ORDER BY, LIMIT 2 queries or a UNION

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ten highest:

```
SELECT Username, Rating FROM <Table> ORDER BY Rating DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Ten lowest:

```
SELECT Username, Rating FROM <Table> ORDER BY Rating ASC LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

You order the result and use `limit 10`

```
select *
from mytable
order by rating
limit 10
```

or the top highest values

```
select *
from mytable
order by rating desc
limit 10
```